# To find a point of intersection between 2 functions, why is the solution to make each function equal the other?

Tags: functions, proof-verification, proof-explanation, quadratics

If $f(x)=x^2−6x+14$ and $g(x)=−x^2−20x−k$, determine the value of $k$ so that there is exactly one point of intersection between the two parabolas.

I want to clarify that I know how to solve this problem.

My question: why does making both function equal each other allow us to determine that point of intersection? I am interested in the proof if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: The point of intersection $(x,y)$ is the point where the two functions have the same $x$ values at the same $y$ values. Setting them equal is just like setting the $y$ values equal.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

A point of first parabola has coordinates
$$(x,f(x))$$
a point of the second parabola is of the form
$$(x,g(x))$$

the point of the intersection must satisfy
$$(x,f(x))=(x,g(x))$$
thus
$$f(x)=g(x).$$

Comment: I would probably pose the general points as $(a, f(a))$ and $(b, g(b))$ and then require $(a, f(a)) = (b, g(b))$.  (Makes it easier later to figure out how to find intersections between two more general parametric curves, for example.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler But you have $a=b$.

Comment: Ok this clears up my confusion. The y coordinates f(x) and g(x) must be the same, in order for both function to intersect at the same point of x. Thus the logical conclusion for both functions to equal each other.

Comment: @yung_philosopher Yah{}{}{}{}{}{[

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$f(x)=g(x)\implies f(x)-g(x)=0$$

So set $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)=2x^2+14x+(14+k)=0$

and use the discriminant to find when this has only one solution.

Comment: I just realised the last part is irrelevant to your question. Sorry. First part answers it though I believe

Comment: The OP wants to know _why_ you set $f(x)=g(x)$ in the first place.